# Flutter: Authentication with Azure AD B2C returns result but with empty accesstoken

Tags: flutter, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I try to build a Flutter app with Azure B2C authentication. To achive this I use the [Flutter App Auth Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth). At first sight everything seems to work as expected, but when I looked at the result the accesstoken is null. What am I missing? Obviously, I can get a connection to Azure and after entering the credentials a result is send back to my app. But why without token?

Debug session of the result:
[Debug session of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ElFD.png)

My configuration:
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e16R3.png)

I call the method like this:

```
  Future<void> _login() async{
AuthorizationTokenResponse result;
try{
  result = await _appauth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
    AuthorizationTokenRequest(_clientId, _redirectUrl,
        discoveryUrl: _discoveryUrl,
        scopes: _scopes),
  );
}
catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
}
if (result != null) {
  _processAuthTokenResponse(result);
}
```

}

Does anybody know what I forgot?
Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t giving a scope to a resource so you don’t get an access token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens

Comment: I added the scopes to the request?
`AuthorizationTokenRequest(_clientId, _redirectUrl,
        discoveryUrl: _discoveryUrl,
        **scopes: _scopes**),`

Comment: But what is in your scopes? It needs to contain the identifier uri and scope name of a resource you configured as an app registration as per the article.

Comment: My scope looks like this:

  `final List<String> _scopes = <String>[
    'openid',
    'profile',
    'email',
    'offline_access',
  ];`
According to openid connect scopes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
Am I mixing something up?

Comment: Read the link again. Those scopes are not to any resource. You need to create another web app that acts as the resource and assign the permissions and generate a new scope. You put that scope in your array and then it’ll work.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, can you please help me by maybe providing a like to an article to describes and explains the process of doing just that. "Those scopes are not to any resource. You need to create another web app that acts as the resource and assign the permissions and generate a new scope. You put that scope in your array and then it’ll work"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga